# How to configure Inverse Search with WinEdt + Okular configuration?

Tags: pdftex, winedt, forward-inverse-search, preview, okular

My environment is as follows:
OS: Windows 10 Pro: 64bit kept being updated.
WinEdt: Build: 20180507  (v. 10.3) - 64-bit
Okulat: 1.6.70 32-bit
Very sorry, I should have mentioned it.

WinEdt is an excellent Editor for lattexing; I usually use PDFTexfy and preview with Sumatra. SumatraPDF is also nice; it works lightly. But, I am aged and has become quite weak in eyes. 
For me, the font in SumatraPDF preview looks quite thin and get tired soon. 
Or must magnify extremely te preview. 
Adobe Acrobat 11 Pro shows better view, but as I understand synchtex is not supported. 
The PDF font in Oklar preview (on windows 10) appears quite good and, with anti-aliasing switch (for both font and graphics) on, the preview is almost ideal for me.
This is the reason I desire the enveronment WinEdt+Okular.

I note that both inverse and forward search with TeXStudio+Okular configuration 
works fine. The setting is, for your reference,
(a) forward search;
In TeXStudio
External Editor: okular --unique "file:?am.pdf#src:@ ?c:am.tex" 
(b) Inverse Search 
In TeX Studio
Command table: PDFLaTeX: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
Command table: External Editor: okular --unique %.dvi#src:@?c:m.tex
In Okulkar
[Settings]-[Configure Okular...]-[Editor] 
Custom Text 
Editor Command:  texstudio "%f" -line %l

### This works.

The description below
But, I prefer WinEdt to TexStudio from my personal history.
Besides, I cannot switch on the Okular's the antialising under this preview mode.

I tried in Okular replacing 
texstudio "%f" -line %l
by
(1) "C:\Program Files\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 10\WinEdt.exe" "[Open(|%f|);SelPar(%l,10);]" 
(2) "C:\Program Files\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 10\WinEdt.exe" "%f" -line %l
but, both did not work.
In WinEdt, I used PDFTeXfy with PDFLaTex + synch tex. synch=+1 -1 both tried.
The Tex studio command line contains .dvi. Is this the cause of my failure in WinEdt?
Should i use dviout somwhere?
Slight questionable thing is that, not only getting failure (nothing occurs at mouse click) 
at (1) or (2), but also the texstudio setting "%f" -line %l seems remaining somewher in PC
even though (1) or (2) is written in the command line,
because I can still work Inverse searching with TeXStudio+Okular configuration.

If an expert help me, and devise WinEdt + Okular setteing, I would be most grateful.
Perhaps it will help also old people greatly. Thanking in advance.

Comment: It may help to confirm version of Win Edit 103-64 ? and operating system e.g. is it Win10x64 ? what about Okular 1.5.70 ?

Comment: The font in a PDF should be the same in any previewer and only zoom should change the visibility in SumatraPDF for ocular to win edit you can try based on my answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442295/setup-synctex-with-textadept-and-okular/451413#451413 replacing the command (5) with "C:\Program Files\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 10\WinEdt.exe" "[Open(|%f|);SelLine(%l,8)]" you will need to test that first as my notes say some users need SelPar and some use ' in place of | bars

Comment: Many Thanks, KJO. I have added the version info in my original question. WinEdt :Build: 20180507  (v. 10.3) - 64-bit, Okular 
Version 1.6.70, 32bit (in program_files x86), OS: Windows 10 Pro; all updates done. I am thankful for your detailed instruction. But, the first method had been already test  in failure; and other options changing (1) | to ', (2) SelPar to SelLine (3) Last 8 to Last 10 (4) did not work neither.

Comment: Sorry (4)  -C switch to WinEdt also checked.   How should I proceed? You should know very deep. Toku

Comment: Great! Thank you KJO. After my comment (report of failure), I have roll back Okular to 1.6.70. Then, with pleasing surprise Reverse Search worked at your suggested line

Comment: After my last report 2 hour ago, I uninstalled Okular and re-installer the build one year ago. okular-master-264-windows-msvc2017_32-cl.exe. (ver 1.6.70 again).  Then, delightfully your suggested line

Comment: "C:\Program Files\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 10\WinEdt.exe" -C="WinEdt 10.3" "[Open('%f');SelLine(%l,10)]"  worked!!!  How nice! As for your comparison of Sumatra and Okular, I slightly prefer the left one. (I am crazily keen on thin fonts.)  I emphasize both acrobat 11 pro and Okular with antialising on fonts give me easier looking than Sumatra.   In any case,I conclude with thank you to your wonderful help!

Answer (score 1):

There should be no difference in readability of a PDF when previewed in a Viewer at the same zoom size. Here the same document is open in the same screen in both SumatraPDF and Okular

[image]

The Reverse search command for both viewers should be similar. The last number is your choice of colour (8 is turquoise whilst 10 is blue) so you can use either. Some users prefer SelLine in place of the SelPar and it may be easier to use ' in place of the vertical bar symbol |

"C:\Program Files\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 10\WinEdt.exe" "[Open(|%f|);SelPar(%l,8)]"

"C:\Program Files\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 10\WinEdt.exe" "[Open('%f');SelLine(%l,10)]"

On some occasions WinEdt 103 configures an additional Application Caption identifier command -C="WinEdt 10.3" so you may eventually use a final command of

"C:\Program Files\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 10\WinEdt.exe" -C="WinEdt 10.3" "[Open('%f');SelLine(%l,10)]"

It should work instantly in any .pdf that has a valid **.synctex**(.gz) and .tex file so a double left click in SumatraPDF or Shift & left click in Okular will open WinEdt with the .tex file at the correct position.

In WinEdt the command to preview the pdf is F8 and will open whichever PDF viewer is set in Options > Execution Modes > PDF Viewer and WinEdt has an automatic configurator that works very well with its preferred viewer SumatraPDF.